# ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions: No such file or directory compilation terminated. exit status 1

Tags: arduino, project, arduino-uno, arducam

i am trying to follow this tutorial on Arducam Mini 2MP SPI Camera Module for Arduino:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hybQpjwJ4aA

i have copied the files ArduCAM,ArduCAM-Touch,OV7670FIFO & UTFT4ArduCAM_SPI to arduino-1.8.19/examples

please help me with this
thank you!

i get these errors while running the file ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions:

Arduino: 1.8.19 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"
ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions:11:21: fatal error: ArduCAM.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
ArduCAM.h: No such file or directory
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Arduino: 1.8.19 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"
ArduCAM_Mini_2MP_OV2640_functions:13:25: fatal error: memorysaver.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
memorysaver.h: No such file or directory
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.